# Laravel + React: this.state.tasks.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I cannot iterate over items I put into state from a dummy API get endpoint:

[image]

This is my entire component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class TaskList extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            tasks: [], // I set the empty state for now
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/tasks') // I fetch the data
            .then(response =>{
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(tasks=>{
                this.setState({tasks}); // I put the data into the state
            });
    }

    renderTasks() {
        return this.state.tasks.map(task => { // Here I want to iterate over the state and it fails
            return (
                <li>{task.title}</li>
            );
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.renderTasks()}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default TaskList;

if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<TaskList/>, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

Function `map` does not see the data. Why?

[image]

> app.js:57174 Uncaught TypeError: this.state.tasks.map is not a
>   function

I can console log `console.log(this.state)` inside `renderTasks()` and I get:

[image]

Comment: Did you forget to parse your JSON? I tl ooks like it is trying to map over a string?

Comment: Well there is your answer, you can't use map() on a Object

Comment: I add data to work on an array `return this.state.tasks.data.map(task => {` but this does not work as well. Am I blind? I'm missing something…

Comment: Yeah you should only try to map if tasks is not empty. ;) Now it will break still the first time because data key doesnt exist in the empty tasks array

Comment: I edited my answer so now if data is undefined it will map over an empty array the first time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

map function can be applied only on array not on object, as shown in the image `tasks` is object but `tasks.data` is array. You should set state as follows:

```
.then(tasks=>{
          this.setState({tasks: tasks.data}); // putt array rather than object
  });
```

This can also be achieve by(if above solution is not applied):

```
this.state.tasks.data.map();
```

Comment: That did the trick. I should set the state from `tasks.data`. Then I can map via `return this.state.tasks.map(task =>`. Damn JS frameworks! Hate them. Thank you Umair.

Answer (score 1):

You try to map over the object that holds the data Array. You should map over data-array inside the tasks object :)

```
  renderTasks() {
            const {tasks: {data}} = this.state;
            return ([] || data).map(task => { // Here I want to iterate over the state and it fails
                return (
                    <li>{task.title}</li>
                );
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
renderTasks() {
    if (this.state.tasks.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
        return this.state.tasks.data.map(task => { // Here I want to iterate over the state and it fails
            return (
                <li>{task.title}</li>
            );
        })
    } else {
        return (null);
    }
}
```

when the component renders for the first time, using `this.state.tasks.data.map` would fail because data is not a key in `this.state.tasks` as fetch is only triggered after the `DidMount()`.

What this does is, if this.state.tasks has data key, then map through that data other wise return null.